# Execute action when cursor enters a cell

Tags: excel, vba

is it possible to trigger an event, when the cursor **enters** a specific cell?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **event macros.**  Here is an example giving a message if cell **B9** is clicked:

Enter the following code in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Range("B9"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    MsgBox "B9 clicked"
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

Macros must be enabled for this to work!

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible. Please find the sample code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Row = 2 And Target.Column = 2 Then
    MsgBox "hello"
End If

End Sub
```

So when you enter the cell B2 you will get Hello msgbox. You can replace your actions instead of the MsgBox.

Comment: You should point out that this code needs to go inside the predefined module for the desired sheet.  Also, how would you do this dynamically?  For instance, if you add a sheet at runtime, how do you fire this event?